# Problems starting Excel from .Net application

Tags: c#, excel, excel-interop

I have a .Net 4 web application which opens excel and inserts some data from SQL Server. All works fine on local dev machine.

When I transferred it on to a laptop to show the user however, when I click the command button to open excel and export the data, excel does not open but the workbook is locked making it look like something is trying to happen.

The only difference I can see is the code is looking to open a .xls but the laptop has office 2010 (the dev machine had 2010 and 2003) so opens the .xls in compatibility mode when I open it manually.

Other than reworking the code is there anything I can configure on the laptop to get excel to open as is?

Don't have access to the source at the moment so can't post any code.

Comment: `"When it doubt, cout."` Basically, try to do some debugging.  Since it's a client machine, you might resort to logging or outputting to a console window on the side, or a file... there are plenty of options.

Comment: You are probably using 2003 interop in your code? Check your project references

Comment: You might want to read [Considerations for server-side Automation of Office](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/257757): "Microsoft does not currently recommend, and does not support, Automation of Microsoft Office applications from any unattended, non-interactive client application or component (including ASP, ASP.NET, DCOM, and NT Services), because ..."

Comment: updated it to use 2010 but still the same - debugging on the dev machine shows nothing as it worls so think i'll just output to a text file on the laptop and see what come of that.  thanks